# how to fix kafka consumer lag in 0.10.2.1 kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Facing issue with kafka consumer lag. 
Now we are restarting kafka consumer to reduce the lag. Need help for the fix.

We have three brokers and 6 consumer consuming.

Comment: You should provide more details about your situation: 1) What version of Kafka are you on?  2). Can you give us the relevant code of your consumer?

Comment: 6 consumers for how many partitions?

Answer (score 2):

Restarting the consumers are not likely to solve the issue. I'd suggest the following series of actions:

- Monitor how much lag is getting reduced in unit time (per minute, let's assume) by each consumer. You can derive it by dividing the total reduction of lag by six.
- If the rate of lag reduction is still too low, and you'd like to increase it, then add appropriate number of consumers. You can get an estimate of the number of additional consumers from the previous step.
- Make sure all your consumers are in the same consumer group.

Comment: You can only add consumers up to the number of partitions, though

Comment: Yup, that's true. I was assuming he has multiples of 6 partitions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Mostly performance of broker instance is much higher than consumer. How about increase the partitions of topic and also increase consumers up to partitions. Consuming concurrency can increase performance.
2. If you store offsets on the zookeeper, it can be bottleneck. Reduce commits of offset and use dedicated zookeeper if possible. The best solution is storing offsets on brokers.

Comment: I think increasing the number of partitions won't help in reducing the existing lag. But it's a good practice nonetheless to have #partitions as a multiple of #consumers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when i used a topic with one partition. Soon after my consumer started, lag kept increasing.
What worked for me is that i have deleted existing Kafka topic with below command:

kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic ntift

And created same topic with more than 1 partitions(3 in this case) with below command:

kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --create --topic ntift --partitions 3 --replication-factor 3

Now, restarted my consumer application. After the restart, i didn't see LAG (run the below command to check the LAG):

kafka-console-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group my-consumer-app --describe

GROUP   TOPIC PARTITION CURRENT-OFFSET LOG-END-OFFSET LAG  CONSUMER-ID    HOST   CLIENT-ID
app-grp ntift    0            45             45        0   sarama-9c2dd    / sarama
app-grp ntift    1            44             44        0   sarama-9c2dd    / sarama
app-grp ntift    2            43             43        0   sarama-9c2dd    / sarama

i also noticed that consumer group(i.e, my-consumer-app) was up and running with 3 consumers in it.